# Waiting Tasks on Mirror

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring, windows-server, waits

I just migrated my primary's synchronous mirror to a new server and I've noticed that there are 150 to 230 waiting tasks on the mirrored instance (based on the activity monitor.)  I don't recall if the prior mirror had a similar number, however it seem high to be considering the primary only has 9 waiting tasks total and all of them are related to the mirroring process.

I've tried the `sp_BlitzWho` and the `sp_whoisactive` scripts to try and identify what is executing and waiting however they return nothing for the default execution.  When I run `sp_whoisactive @show_system_spids = 1` I see mirroring commands with wait info attached but only around 16 and they are all attached to the master database.  Using the plain old `sp_who` which returns on average 250 results with a good 2/3 of them being the command `DB MIRROR`.  They don't seem to be attached to any database and all of the mirrored databases say they are synchronized.

Why would the mirror have so many waiting tasks to synchronize mirror 5 databases with very little data changes happening on the primary?  Is this normal behavior?

**Update**

I've rebooted the mirror and the wait tasks come right back.  I've reviewed the disk IO and some of the files will have a 8 to 10 ms wait time on them which doesn't make a lot of sense to me as very little is being transferred from the primary < 100KB per sec on average.  Nothing seems impacted by the waiting tasks on the primary or secondary.

*Environment Details*

Primary -

- 64 Core / 488 GB
- 2 NVMe drives for tempdb data and log
- Nitro Hypervisor

Mirror -

- 128 Core / 1.9 TB
- (2) SSD drives for tempdb data and log
- Xen Hypervisor
  Common -
- VM Windows 2012 R2
- SQL Server EE 2008 R2 10.50.6000.34
- (2) 1.4 TB Drives with 3000 Dedicated IOPS (Data)
- (2) 300 GB Drives with 800 Dedicated IOPS (Log) *Only one log per DB*
- Power Mode High Performance
- 25 Gb/s NIC
- MAXDOP Set to 8
- Parallelism Threshold set to 50
- Instant Disk Initialization granted to service account

*Mirroring Config*

- Sync Mirroring High Availability no witness
- Mirroring 5 databases

**Update 2**
[image]

All of the waits seem to be focused on DBMIRROR_SEND wait type.  I just applied a security update for SQL Server (KB4035316) but that made no improvement on the waiting tasks.

**Update 3**
sp_Blitz output

```
- ANSI NULL Default Enabled
- Agent Jobs Without Failure Emails
- Agent XPs
- Backups Not Performed Recently
- Database Mail XPs
- Database Owner <> SA
- Extended Events Hyperextension
- Extended Stored Procedures in Master
- Forced Parameterization Enabled
- Forced Parameterization On
- Inactive Tables Without Clustered Indexes
- Jobs Owned By Users
- Last good DBCC CHECKDB over 2 weeks old
- No failsafe operator configured
- Possibly Broken Log Shipping
- Recursive Triggers Enabled
- Server restarted in last 24 hours
- Stats Updated Asynchronously
- Sysadmins
- System Database on C Drive
- Tables in the Master Database
- TempDB Has >16 Data Files
- Transaction Log Larger than Data File
- User Databases on C Drive
- User-Created Statistics In Place
- clr enabled
- cost threshold for parallelism
- max degree of parallelism
- max server memory (MB)
- remote admin connections
- show advanced options
```

Comment: Can you give more information about new server, does it has same specification as the one before. Is the storage same ?

Comment: Are you encountering any issues due to waiting tasks ? How many dbs are mirrored ? Is the power plan on new server set to high performance ?

Comment: Updated the question with additional information.

Comment: So your mirror is twice + more powerful than your primary :-). Is the disk Allocation size on primary and secondary the same ? Any errors you see in sql server or windows event logs ?

Comment: @Kin
Only errors I see are in the **Windows Application Log** for a perflib and perflibnet
  Event ID '-1073740816' in Source 'Perflib' cannot be found
  Event ID '-1073739820' in Source 'PerfNet' cannot be found
**Windows System - **
Registering a publisher to Channel Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-ShimEngine/Operational
**SQL Log -** 
Cannot use Large Page Extensions:  lock memory privilege was not granted.

Comment: @Kin and yes the mirror is twice the power and the disk allocation sizes are the same on all of the disks with the exception of the tempdb storage as they are smaller and on ssds and not nvm drives.

Comment: as last resort - [run sp_blitz](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit#sp_blitz-overall-health-check) `@OutputType = 'MARKDOWN'` . If I cant find anything interesting, I will head off :-)

Comment: @Kin only thing that stands out to me is having CDC enabled on two of the databases.  Had that on for some data migrations.  I'll compare the list to the current primary to see if something stands out.

Comment: If you are not using cdc turn it off .. that should help as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81139/discussion-between-aaron-and-kin).

Comment: Did you turn off CDC - if it is not being used ? & post the output of sp_blitz as I suggested.

Comment: It’s disabled on the primary. I’m going to restore the backup from the primary with it off to the mirror in a couple of hours. I’ll post the output shortly

Comment: CDC is now disabled on the primary and the mirrored database @Kin.  No improvement on waiting tasks.